# how to handle returned objects from findBy....Exists (boolean exists) in Spring-Data-MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB called 'customers' where I store documents with different schemas.

In my Spring Boot Application I have the following Repository:

```
public interface BgradeCustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<BgradeCustomer, String> {
    public List<BgradeCustomer> findByScoreExists(boolean exists);
}
```

When I invoke findByScoreExists and pass true, it works fine and I get the collection of objects with property 'score', but the problem is when I pass false to findByScoreExists, I get the collection of 'BgradeCustomer' objects with only the common properties with the other schemas !!

I changed the method signature to be:

```
// Customer is the other schema in the collection 
public List<Customer> findByScoreExists(boolean exists);
```

but that never worked, I always get 'java.lang.NullPointerException: null'

So, how can I get all the objects that doesn't have a specific property ?

Comment: If your score is a primitive type, try using a wrapper class. It maybe that setting null to a primitive type is throwing `NullPointerException`

Comment: I tried, it didn't work !

Answer (score 1):

wrap the object with java.util.Optional
then use method isPresent() to check